# "At least one of ID token and access token is required" with google signin flow with firebase emulator suite

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, firebase-tools

I am trying to test google signin flow with firebase emulator suite. The issue is google sign-in are not receive `idToken` all the time but firebase emulator suite only supports `id_token`, So I can't login through this approach.

Edited:

```
 Future<UserCredential> signInWithGoogle() async {
    // Trigger the authentication flow
    final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();

    // Obtain the auth details from the request
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication? googleAuth =
        await googleUser?.authentication;

    // Create a new credential
    final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      // Didn't fill accessToken arg cause firebase emulator only supports idToken.
      // accessToken: googleAuth?.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth?.idToken,
    );

    // Once signed in, return the UserCredential
    return await firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  }
```

I get this error `'accessToken != null || idToken != null': At least one of ID token and access token is required` when call `GoogleAuthProvider.credential`, With `accessToken` I am able to login on real firebase project successfully and both are tested in debug mode with API 31 Emulator, So SHA-1 should been set successfully.

Google sign-in version `google_sign_in: ^5.4.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flutterfire cli doc says:

> if your Flutter app supports Android then the Android Google Services Gradle plugin will automatically be applied for you.

But seems it's not working for me, I have tried 0.2.0 and 0.2.4 both didn't add google-services plugin for me. So just add it manually.

Comment: For anyone wondering how to get this done, check out the [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).

Comment: OMG, I'm scratching my head for hours for this invincible bug...